# Spark Lost Executor and Shuffle Index Not found Issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pipeline of operations on a huge data set (~500GB), that includes repartitioning, some transformations and finally saving to disk as text file. The pipeline looks like this.

```
sc.textFile("").persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY).repartition(1000).filter { ""}.map { "" }.mapPartitions("").saveAsTextFile("")
```

As per the spark engine, the pipeline operates in two stages, at first it repartitions the data doing a lot of shuffling, which works perfectly normal, however, as soon as the next phase gets executed, it keeps on loosing executors, I have tried various configurations to increase ack time etc, however nothing seems to work.

Also, while in the second stage, it is also unable to find the shuffle index files and restarts both the stages again.

Any help would be really appreciated.